# How to Change value of lable in qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, html, qualtrics

I want to change the value of the question lable in qualtrics from the default to something else.
Please see the code below:

```
<label for="QR~QID8" class="QuestionText BorderColor">Click to write the question text</label>
 <h2 class="noStyle">
 <label for="QR~QID8" class="QuestionText BorderColor">Click to write the question text </label>
 </h2>
 <div class="QuestionBody">
 <div class="ChoiceStructure"> 
 <input autocomplete="off" id="QR~QID8" value="" class="InputText QR-QID8 QWatchTimer" name="QR~QID8~TEXT" data-runtime-textvalue="runtime.Value" type="TEXT"> 
 </div></div>
```

so when my user answers the previous question. the question should change from "Click to write the question text" the the previous answer . 
For example if user gives ABC as an answer. The new question text should be "ABC" rather than "Click to write the question text"

Comment: Are you trying to update on the same page or a separate page? It feels like this could just be done with some carry forward options.

Comment: no buddy. I have to do this on the same page which cannot be done by piping values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

```
var label = document.querySelector('label[for="QR~QID8"]');
    label.textContent =document.getElementById('QR~QID2').value;
```